# C++: Checking input data

Tags: c++

I have to write a C++ program to specify a character from input if it is a number or word or symbol? Firstly I used ASCII to solve that, but the problem is when the input is not a character in ASCII, example it is in UTF-16, it is a Korean word...
So what can I do to solve?
Thank you!

Comment: You might have a look at `iswdigit`

Comment: hi, use wide character to support UTF chars

Comment: Take a look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide

Answer (score 0):

wchar_t should be the one you are looking for.
In C++, wchar_t is a distinct fundamental type (and thus it is not defined in  nor any other header).